# How can I fix my system lagging due to problems with Firefox plugin-container process (IOGraphicsAccelerator, too many contexts)

Tags: macos, safari, gpu, firefox

I was running a google meet call in Firefox and had a few other tabs open, including a gitlab one with an embedded video (which *might* have been part of the cause of this) when I noticed considerable lagging in the responsiveness of windows, not just firefox. I found the following conspicuous messages in the console app:

```
IOGraphicsAccelerator::newUserClient(): process plugin-container (PID 1934) has too many contexts (510) + queues (0) + device (171) + shared (171) created. Possibly leaking?
```

It also affects opening browser tabs in e.g. Safari and general system responsiveness.

I couldn't find much on this kind of error message other than the plugin-container process seems to belong to Firefox.

This is a Macbook Pro with macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Firefox solved that issue for me, I no longer observe said messages in the console app and the system behaves as usual.